# Git command to checkout latest commit from develop branch

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-clone, git-checkout

Using groovy syntax in Jenkins pipeline, below is the syntax used for check out:

```
         git branch: branchName, 
                       credentialsId: credential, 
                       url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}.git"
```

Where `credential` is jenkins credential(`111111-222222-33333-44444`) shown below:

### [image]

jenkins does the following under the hood, for groovy syntax(above):

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc/def.git
 > git init /app/jenkins/workspace/../def # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc/def.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials abcuser
 > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc/def.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc/def.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc/def.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc/def.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials abcuser
 > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc/def.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision 5df59884ecb3aa1b55aabf99ab8bd0adcd4eb41b (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
Commit message: "new commit"
```

---

For the given groovy syntax, What is the equivalent git command suffice to run on shell? Does `git clone -branch` or `git checkout` would not suffice? Why Jenkins is running `git fetch` multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, following need to happen. Your credential in Jenkins need to be a private key.

Authentication phase:

```
# optional. check whether the gitLabServer is already trusted
ssh-keygen -F ${gitLabServer} 
# adds the gitLabServer into known_hosts. This stops interactive prompts during git clone.
ssh-keyscan ${gitLabServer} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Add your existing private key (like id_rsa) into authentication agent
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add /path/to/key/credential
```

Git clone phase:

```
# Finally, clone the repo with branchName as a parameter
git clone -b ${branchName} git@${gitLabServer}:${projectName}/${repo}.git
```

Comment: The private key need to be located at /path/to/key/credential. Do you require any other clarification?

Comment: So, mainly to build the code, from specific branch. we should strictly `git clone -b <branchname>`

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is

```
git checkout branchName
```

Comment: But we need to give credential id instead of username/passwd for authentication

Comment: @overexchange `git` has no concept of credentials. Or even username/password. Authentication is provided by another service on top of git, such as https or SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a certificate as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422632/1573395)

If your repo provider support token based communication as github add token to repo url https://[token here]@github.com/[your name]/[your repo].git
See [the documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) to know how to provide token.

You also can use something as:

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<repo>
```

But we understand that it's the unsecured way and strongly not recommended to use it.

Comment: credential id in Jenkins corresponds to the private key used from jenkins

Comment: Then it's all OK just configure git once to use key and that's it.

Comment: What is the single command to checkout develop branch from a repo(.git)?

Comment: git  pull origin ${ branch_name} After you configure your jenkins git to use ```git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git```

Comment: Updated query with more info