# Jenkins - BitBucket git push : could not read Password for No such device or address

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, bitbucket

I was trying to push my commits to **bitbucket** using **shell script** in **Jenkins**.

so I know that I have to provide credentials when running **git push** command.

I use Jenkins UI way to those thing, not Pipeline.

I have searched to fix this, but i could not find a way to do this using Shell script in Jenkins.

In my research I found , there is bitbucket pluggin that trigger bitbucket push [Bitbucket Push And Pull Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Push+And+Pull+Request+Plugin). but I have to setup webhooks for that. So Im running the jenkins inside VPN, so because of that I can't use webhooks where bitbucket cant to sent request to my machine. So I thought, running git push using shell script is the way.

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you keep ssh keys on the jenkins slaves ? If so, you dont have to provide password while performing git push

Comment: I did not @Fidel, I only configured with Jenkins credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use username/password in a script, but you have a lot of solutions. 
Please read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803642/1573395) in another thread explains the solutions for working with git into a shell script.

Comment: seems this would be the right answer, so I have to try your method first.\

Comment: I think, way of push commits to reposiory without password by setting up shh keys is right as you said. but with Jenkins I'm getting another kind of problems when I do the way you said. Here is the error when I changed https orgin URL to SSH url. ERROR : invalid hostname".